# How to combine ranges that only contain Strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Three different Ranges]I have 3 ranges (columns) that are being randomly generated. I need to combine the 3 ranges into a new single range but I only want to include the string values (no errors). How would I go about doing that in either base excel or VBA?

I tried `=IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C20)+COUNTA(F2:F20))<=COUNTA(C2:C20),C2:C20,INDEX(F2:F20,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C20)+COUNTA(F2:F20))-COUNTA(C2:C20)))`
I realize this would only combine the first two columns and originally I thought it would carry forward the string values but it also carries over the error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(C2:I20,1,4,7),2)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I am pretty new to excel so I'm not really sure what formulas are available to me. Sometimes it doesn't seem that straight forward. Thank you.